# Android SQLiteDatabase SELECT query take long time

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I have about 1500 records in TABLE_CONTACT. My code to get contacts:

```
public ArrayList<SBContact> getAllContacts() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<SBContact> mContacts = new ArrayList<SBContact>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + SBDatabaseHelper.TABLE_CONTACT;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            SBContact result = new SBContact(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SBDatabaseHelper.CONTACT_NUMBER)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SBDatabaseHelper.CONTACT_NAME)), cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SBDatabaseHelper.EXITS_USER)));
            mContacts.add(result);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return mContacts;
}
```

The problem is: The first time I run this method, it take about `15ms`. 5 seconds later I run this method again, it takes about `20 seconds`.

In similar way, after the first call, 15s later, run method again, it take about `10 seconds`. And after 2 minutes later, run this method again, it take about `15ms` as the first time run.

In this time, no other thread make a read/write query to database.

I don't understand what the `SQLiteDatabase` does. Does it need time to release memory or do something?

**EDITED**
Sorry all, this is not the problem of `SQLiteDatabase`. See my answer to more detail about this case.

Comment: Select only the rows from the Contact you actually use instead of `*`

Comment: Did you mean `columns` instead `rows`? My table have only 2 columns, so, I think use `*` is not the problem.

Comment: yes, sorry i meant columns! good catch additionally may be willing to test query vs. rawQuery on the SQLiteDatabase object for performance difference. How large is this data set?

Comment: why do you want to iterate over the Cursor in `do..while` loop?

Comment: Why do you think you need to load all data?

Comment: Indexing your columns (the ones which you will use in WHERE clauses and the ones you will use in your JOINS) speeds up tremendously (I had a 400x boost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry all, my mistake.

This problem does not relate with `SQLiteDatabase`. It due to `AsyncTask` problem.

My case is: I run a AsyncTask to get contact from local database (sqlite), and at same time, I start new thread works with server (call api take a long time) in this AsyncTask. When I run the AsyncTask to get contacts again (with `execute` method), the old AsyncTask still running, and it prevent new one run. That's the reason the new task take a long time to finish.
I have fix by use `executeOnExecutor` method, and the result of method return immediately.

One again, sorry all.

Answer (score 2):

Close your cursor after each query

Comment: Thank you, my mistake, but it does not solve the problem